# Removing characters that are uncommon in the comparison of two strings

Tags: c++

```
string word1 = "misisipi";
string word2 = "mississippi";
```

I would like to 'compare' these strings some how and be able to 'toss out' letters that are not common.
For example word2 would be cut down to `"misisipi"`, making sure to keep the 'S'es in order, and `word1` would not change since all of its characters are in `word2`.  I recognize how to remove an element in a string, but this time I want to maintain the order.  For example, if I did **not** maintain the order, after comparison `word2` would be `"missipi"`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Please post the code you tried that almost works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying the valid `word2` characters into `word1` as you iterate through each element of `word1`.

```
std::string temp;
std::string::iterator w2 = word2.begin();

for(std::string::iterator w1 = word1.begin(); w1 != word1.end(); ++w1)
{
    for(; w2 != word2.end(); ++w2)    // Move through word2...
    {
        if(*w1 == *w2)    // Copy the character into temp when found.
        {
            temp += *w2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

std::cout << temp << std::endl;
```

May want to allocate `temp` beforehand, if you want speed.